# Filter rows in R conditional on its value in comparison to other rows in the data frame

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm trying to create a reference list so that when I encounter a first name I am able to assign a gender to it. Complete accuracy is not important.

I have a list of names, corresponding gender, and count of name/gender pair from the Social Security Administration in this form:

```
Name   Gender   Count  
Aaron    F       10    
Aaron    M       7246     
Abbie    F       242    
Abbie    M       8
```

As one can tell, there are lots of unisex names in the data. I want to get rid of the rare name/gender pairs when the name is both male and female.

I always turn to dplyr with a problem like this, and I know that I could filter on absolute values such as when count > 100. However, I don't want to filter out rare names, just when that rare name/gender pair is much smaller than the other name/gender pair.

How do I write code to accomplish something like this:

`filter x when Name=Name and Count < 10*Count`

**EDIT:** Thanks for the help guys. I realize that I was unclear in my initial post.

I'd like to be able to have one record for names where I'm relatively sure of the gender. (e.g. Aaron from the above example would have Gender = M). This is why I'd like to create a filter rule for if the count of one gender/name pair is 10 times greater than the other gender/name pair. However, if the counts are close, I will assign this gender as U for unisex as we are not as positive in assigning a gender to this name. (Not worried about preserving the correct count value.)

Expected output would be something like this:

```
Name  Gender Count
Aaron M      7246
Abbie F      242
Alva  U      150
```

Comment: Based on the example, I guess you will get 0 rows, right.  Your second question is not clear `filter x when Name=Name and Count < 10*Count`  Please do show the expected result and an example that represents the data

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it still is not clear.  In the original dataset, there was no "Alva".  Suppose, if `Alva` have "M" and "F" rows, and the Counts are "150" and "170".  Which one of the Count would you take for the "Alva" row, given that the Gender is now "U"?  I did see the comment that "not worried about preserving the correct count value".  Does it imply that it can be a random row, max Count, min Count etc..

Comment: Do you know about the gender package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gender/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a very useful dataset to work with, so I made a new one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(randomNames)
set.seed(2)
randomize.gender <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(y) {
    c(y, "Male","Female")[sample(1:3,1,prob=c(.82,.09,.09))]
  })
}
df <- data.frame(Name=randomNames(n=10,
                       gender=c("Male","Female"),
                       which.names="first"),
                 Gender=c("Male","Female"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  sample_n(1000,replace=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Gender = randomize.gender(Gender))

      Name Gender
1  Brianne Female
2    Julia Female
3   Kelsey Female
4   Claude   Male
5  Cameron   Male
6   Nathan   Male
7   Claude   Male
8   Nathan   Male
9   Kelsey Female
10  Kelsey Female
..     ...    ...
```

To solve your problem, you first need a function to determine the most used gender based on the ratio of observed genders:

```
determine.gender <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(y) {
    # prop.F is the proportion of instances that a name is female
    cutoff.ratio <- 1/10
    if(y < cutoff.ratio) {
      "Male"
    } else if(y >= 1-cutoff.ratio) {
      "Female"
    } else {
      "Unisex"
    }
  })
}
```

Then you can use a little bit of dplyr and tidyr magic to get your solution

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  count(Name,Gender) %>%
  spread(Gender, n) %>%
  mutate(prop.F = Female/(Female+Male)) %>%
  mutate(likely.gender = determine.gender(prop.F))

       Name Female Male    prop.F likely.gender
1   Brianne     80    8 0.9090909        Female
2   Cameron     12   86 0.1224490        Unisex
3    Claude      5   95 0.0500000          Male
4  Isabella     88   11 0.8888889        Unisex
5     Julia     84    7 0.9230769        Female
6    Kelsey     86    6 0.9347826        Female
7     Linda     98   11 0.8990826        Unisex
8    Nathan     14   88 0.1372549        Unisex
9   William     12   94 0.1132075        Unisex
10    Zamir     15  100 0.1304348        Unisex
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edited post, we could create a logical function ("f1", "f2"), group the data by "Name", replace the elements in "Gender" and "Count" by "U" and the first value of "Count" (by group) i.e. `Count[1L]`, if all the elements in "Count" are TRUE based on "f1".  Get the `unique` rows, and `filter` the rows (`filter(f1(Count))`)

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(x,y) x*10 > max(x) & n_distinct(y) >1
f2 <- function(x) x*10 > max(x)
df %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(GenderN=replace(Gender, all(f1(Count, Gender)), 'U'), 
         Count=replace(Count, all(f1(Count, Gender)), Count[1L])) %>% 
    select(-Gender)%>%
    rename(Gender=GenderN)%>%
    unique() %>%    
    filter(f2(Count))
 #    Name Count Gender
 #1  Aaron  7246      M
 #2  Abbie   242      F
 #3   Alva   150      U
 #4    Amy   180      F
 #5 Benson   120      M
```

Or using `data.table`, we can convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT(df)`).  If all the elements in the "Count" by group ("Name") are TRUE based on the function ("f1"), replace the "Gender", "Count" elements (i.e. "U", first value of "Count") or else return the subset of data.table (`.SD`) and apply the function on the "Count" column in that subset to filter the rows. (`.SD[f1(Count)]`)

```
 library(data.table)
 f1 <- function(x,y) x*10 > max(x) & uniqueN(y) >1
 setDT(df)[, if(all(f1(Count, Gender))) list(Gender='U', 
             Count=Count[1L]) else .SD[f2(Count)], Name]
 #     Name Gender Count
 #1:  Aaron      M  7246
 #2:  Abbie      F   242
 #3:   Alva      U   150
 #4:    Amy      F   180
 #5: Benson      M   120
```

#### EDIT

If you need all the rows of the "Unisex" instead of the above, replace `Count[1L]` by `Count`

```
 setDT(df)[, if(all(f1(Count, Gender))) list(Gender='U', Count=Count) 
                      else .SD[f2(Count)], Name]
 #     Name Gender Count
 #1:  Aaron      M  7246
 #2:  Abbie      F   242
 #3:   Alva      U   150
 #4:   Alva      U   170
 #5:    Amy      F   180
 #6: Benson      M   120
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Name = c("Aaron", "Aaron", "Abbie", "Abbie", "Alva", 
 "Alva", "Amy", "Benson"), Gender = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "M", 
 "F", "F", "M"), Count = c(10L, 7246L, 242L, 8L, 150L, 170L, 180L, 
 120L)), .Names = c("Name", "Gender", "Count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```